# Why does Skyler White leave home early and come back in the evening?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, breaking-bad

I recently finished the second season of Breaking Bad and was left with a question:

After Walter White lies to Skyler and the problems begin in the marriage, she starts to leave home early morning and come back in the evening. Ok, she is upset, I get it, but the series never showed where she goes or what her intention was leaving home. Is she seeing someone behind Mr. White's back? Did I miss something in the season?

If those answers will be revealed in the future seasons, you might try to hide specific details behind spoiler blocks.

Comment: Skyler believes his illness has strained the family's finances and returns to her old job working as an accountant for Ted Beneke -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyler_White

Comment: No, it's a few episodes before she starts to looking for a job. It's something else

Comment: I don't know for sure without going back and watching the episode in question.  However I took this as her deliberately getting back at Walter for his strange behavior and time spent out of the home by repaying that with the same.  She just spends a lot of time out of the house and is vague about where she was - she could have been visiting friends or shopping.  The point is that she wanted to make a point to Walter about his behavior.

Comment: @iandotkelly That's a good one. Do you want to post it as a answer? So I can give you the accept sign

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My interpretation of this behavior is that Skyler has given up complaining to Walt about his strange behavior, in particular disappearing from the house for long periods of time and then being vague about his whereabouts.

She appears to be giving him 'his own medicine', by copying the behavior she finds so worrying and frustrating.  She is deliberately just disappearing from the house and being vague when Walt inquires about her day. She could be doing anything, visiting friends, shopping, it doesn't matter.  The point is that she is probably doing nothing particular other than annoying Walt.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, she started a job at Beneke's and then got involved with him on personal levels, like visiting his home.

Comment: A comment from @Max indicates that this happens before the job.

Comment: Ok. Then I believe what you have commented in the post is the correct answer.